# IE is not working for my ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-7

I have written a simple ajax call which working fine on every browser in my local machine. But when I uploaded the code on my server My ajax call working fine for most of the browser except IE. It is throwing me the error: `access is denied error`. What is this? I am newbie in ajax or jquery. Any helpful suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a little yellow warning triangle in the bottom left of IE?

Comment: Without any details it's impossible to say. The only guess I can make: You are trying to access a resource on a different server, which is not allowed.

Comment: An error has occurred in the script. This message pops up with yellow triangle when testing on IE tester.

Comment: But from local machine and for other browser it is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a cross domain issue. Is the url you are calling in your ajax script from another domain?

Comment: var URL = 'http://example.com/'; // domain And I am calling http://example.com/test

Answer (score 0):

You need to use window.XDomainRequest for IE 8+ for ajax when calling cross domain ajax.

More info about window.XDomainRequest.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd573303(VS.85).aspx

Also, you need to enabled the security setting in IE to allow cross domain access.